# PowerShell - Report on service status

Tags: powershell, service

I am using the below script to monitor a service to see if it is running and then take action.

However it is always executing a true statement, I believe this is because by $running is returning the service with a status of stopped and passing a true response as the service exists.

So the intended purpose is to check the service, if status of stopped email to say it is starting the service. If the service is status of running do nothing.

Any help would be appreciated,

Many thanks

```
$running = Get-Service -Name IISADMIN

if ($running -eq $Stopped) {
                    exit
                    } else {

Start-Service -Name IISADMIN
c:\blat.exe %0 -to email@domain.com -from email@domain.com -subject "Email Subject" -body "Service has been restarted."
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try change it like this:

```
if ($running.status -eq "Stopped")
```

note: if the service does not exist your first line returns an error!
      and maybe you need to invert the condition using:

```
if ($running.status -ne "Stopped")
```

Comment: Hi CB, I tried this already. It still sends an email. However using "Running" instead has worked!

Comment: @user2004752 Check the logic of your condition.. you need to use my last one in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Help from CB above helped, had used "Stopped" previous which didn't work and email was still sent.

However using the below has the script working as expected:

```
if ($running.status -eq "Running")
```